# Convert String Literal to Unicode Icon String

Tags: c#, sql, string, visual-studio-2012, casting

I have a string literal "\\uf001", when I hover over it in debug it gets the extra slash.
However,  should I remove the extra slash "\uf001", while debugging, it gets casted to a char? Unicode Icon.

Is there a way to cast the string to a string (yea I know), with removing the extra slash and make it read a Unicode Icon?
P.S. it's C#, using binding and blend

Comment: You will see \\ in the debugger because that's what it does; the string's value however is `\uf001`

Comment: It's been fixed, after getting half the IT staff on it, the problem was that, one of the rows in the SQL table, was not a correct Unicode code.
After altering all rows to the correct Unicodes, the problem disappeared, odd.
P.S. this was influenced by the binding from Blend.